couldn't run the project
that is flutter.bat fileLaunching lib\main.dart on CPH2235 in debug mode...
Target kernel_snapshot failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.
Command: D:\Flutter\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dartaotruntime.exe --disable-dart-dev D:\Flutter\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server_aot.dart.snapshot --sdk-root D:\Flutter\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4/ -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages D:\Projects\we_chat_app.dart_tool\package_config.json --output-dill D:\Projects\we_chat_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\dde6c439f55e00a749e5c8c86bb319a7\app.dill --depfile D:\Projects\we_chat_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\dde6c439f55e00a749e5c8c86bb319a7\kernel_snapshot.d --incremental --initialize-from-dill D:\Projects\we_chat_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\dde6c439f55e00a749e5c8c86bb319a7\app.dill --source file:///D:/Projects/we_chat_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/Projects/we_chat_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --native-assets D:\Projects\we_chat_app.dart_tool\flutter_build\dde6c439f55e00a749e5c8c86bb319a7\native_assets.yaml --verbosity=error package:we_chat_app/main.dart
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
after i changed jdk from 1.8 to 11 i tried to use firebase and test if google auth working or not that error appears and also i tried cd flutter clean and refreash pub packages and all packages uptodate but i can't fix the error
